Compilation Error in DBT Model: Ambiguous Relation Error with Incremental Materialization
I'm encountering a compilation error with my DBT model while trying to implement incremental materialization. The error message I receive is:
Compilation Error in model validate_columns (models\transforms\validate_columns.sql)
When searching for a relation, dbt found an approximate match. Instead of guessing which relation to use, dbt will move on. Please delete APP.AFTER_VALIDATE_MODEL, or rename it to be less ambiguous.
Searched for: APP.AFTER_VALIDATE_MODEL
Found: APP.AFTER_VALIDATE_MODEL

Here’s the code for my DBT model:
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    alias='AFTER_VALIDATE_MODEL'
) }}

WITH source_data AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(id AS INT) AS id,
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR2(100)) AS name,
        CAST(age AS INT) AS age,
        CAST(gender AS VARCHAR2(100)) AS gender,
        CAST(country AS VARCHAR2(100)) AS country,
        CAST(flag AS INT) AS flag
    FROM {{ ref('testUpload') }}
)

SELECT * FROM source_data

{% if is_incremental() %}
    WHERE id > (SELECT max(id) FROM {{ this }})
{% endif %}


dbt-core Version: 1.8.6
dbt-oracle Version: 1.8.1
Database: Oracle
Incremental Materialization: I'm trying to insert new records based on the maximum id.
Problem:
The error suggests that there’s an ambiguity with the relation APP.AFTER_VALIDATE_MODEL. I have checked and ensured that I don’t have multiple models with the same name, and I'm using the alias in my configuration.
I try every way as I can do such as ephermeral, create view and target run is create or replace view but it still got the same.
Questions:
What could be causing this ambiguous relation error?
How can I resolve it to successfully implement incremental loading in my DBT model?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

"I'm trying to insert new records based on the maximum id." This seems like a flawed approach and you would be better to use a sequence to generate the id values.

yeah but this is just demo code and I trying to insert data from another table
